# Selecting control variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am creating 5 different regression models to measure a single phenomenon, tuition discounts. Tuition discounts are my independent variable in each regression. The Dependent variables are revenue, SAT scores, and percentage of underrepresented races.
Each regression also has control variables such as net tuition price, endowment, total enrollment.
My question is: can I use percentage of race as a control variable for my regression measuring the relationship between tuition discounts and SAT scores?
Percentage of race is a good predictor for SAT scores so it makes sense to use as a control, but it is a dependent variable in one of my other regressions. It seems a little cannibalistic to use the variable in two places.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming adding this variable does not introduce multicollinearity, the main thing you need to be concerned about is endogeneity. I encourage you to look at some of the literature on this problem. If in your model this is not a problem then you can add this predictor.

Here are some links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogeneity_(econometrics)

[http://www.sfu.ca/~pendakur/teaching/buec333/Multicollinearity%20and%20Endogeneity.pdf](http://www.sfu.ca/%7Ependakur/teaching/buec333/Multicollinearity%20and%20Endogeneity.pdf)